# Why the url read as file or directory by the nginx server?

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-location

2017/07/20 06:05:34 [error] 19472#0: *25 open() "/home/websites/gamoto.net/test/categoria/secondi-di-carne" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 175.158.201.6, server: test.gamoto.net, request: "GET /categoria/secondi-di-carne HTTP/1.1", host: "test.gamoto.net", referrer: "http://test.gamoto.net/"

here's there error log.

Comment: Why shouldn't it?  What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know maybe because of the rewrite rule I use?

Comment: Maybe. Show nginx config

Comment: already posted it below :) maybe you can help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name w4.gamoto.net;

  root "R:/gamoto.net/test_html/";

  index index.php;
  #autoindex off;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/chi-siamo/?([a-z-]*)?/?$ /chi-siamo.php?chi=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/categoria/?([a-z-]*)?/?([a-z0-9-]*)?/?$ /categoria.php?cat=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/nazione/italia/?([0-9]*)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=italia&pg=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/nazione/italia/?([a-z0-9-]*)?/?([a-z0-9-]*)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=italia&regione=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/nazione/?([a-z-]*)?/?([0-9-]*)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/ricerca/?([a-z0-9-]*)?/?([0-9]*)?/?$ /ricerca.php?search=$1&pg=$2 last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
    #fastcgi_pass unix:var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  }


  charset utf-8;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```